# How can i get selenium to ignore chrome insecure forms warning

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to get my tests to ignore the chrome warning message of "site is using a connection that's not secure".

What do i need to set to get webdriver to either ignore this, or set the chrome options. Currently its just set as headless.

```
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions(); co.addArguments("headless","disable-gpu");
```

I have tried `--allow-running-insecure-content` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What language are you using to run selenium? C#?

Comment: Given that `addArguments` is written in camelCase, I would guess [tag:java].

Comment: @Jortega im using java

Comment: So i know where in chrome i can disable its under the site setting disable insecure content, but i want to disable it in the driver. The "allow-running-insecure-content" should work... but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `--ignore-certificate-errors`.

```
co.addArguments("headless","disable-gpu", "--ignore-certificate-errors");
```

Also:

```
co.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
co.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
```

Comment: do we need to add the two hyphens... i have seen some examples with and without.

Comment: @user1555190 I think that depends on the language you are using to run selenium.

Comment: If you want to keep trouble shooting we can use this stackoverlfow chat room, someone in there might know.
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230093/discussion-between-user1555190-and-jortega).

Answer (score 0):

this might be due to mixed content, or if your navigating from a https url to http url in your test, explore chrome://flags and localstate in chrome app data folder
https://blog.chromium.org/2020/08/protecting-google-chrome-users-from.html

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions ops = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
System.Collections.ArrayList expPref = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
expPref.Add("mixed-forms-interstitial@2");     
ops.AddLocalStatePreference("browser.enabled_labs_experiments", expPref);
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(service, ops, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```